# Checking who has additional mailboxes added to outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2010

In outlook when you add an additional mailbox is there a way for you to see if someone else has added your mailbox to their outlook to view your emails?

I have a feeling someone has my mailbox added to their outlook as my emails will sometimes go read than quickly unread.

Or is the only way to ask the exchange administrator to verify that?

Thanks

Comment: If you're not the Exchange administrator, then this isn't the right site for you to be asking this on.

Comment: I am not the Exchange administrator. I was mainly curious if it was possible for me (a user) to check this. Sorry for posting my question on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You as an user can't directly verify this, apart from checking any suspicious mail activity.

And even for the Exchange administrator(s), this can be quite difficult to check, as Exchange doesn't explicitly log mailbox accesses anywhere, so this data has to be extrapolated from the system security logs, possibly on multiple servers depending on your Exchange environment, and possibly on very large logs, depending on the number of users.

You can of course ask the Exchange admin(s) to check the permissions on your mailbox, in order to make sure that only you can access it; but if this is not the case, only extended log analysis can actually find who accessed it and when.

Answer (score 2):

Default security would prevent this unless you have granted permission to someone using the Outlook client.  If the defaults have been changed or the admin has done something specifically, hard to say.  Ask the Exchange Admin directly as a start.